# Существует ли способ группировать стили?

Tags: compass, phpstorm, вёрстка, sass, css

Даже юзая sass при верстке, со временем стилей накапливается достаточно много и ориентироваться в них становится сложно, существует ли такая фича в IDE phpstorm (или в другой?) чтобы описания стилей из всего файла (нескольких) для определенного конкретного элемента сгруппировать в одном месте?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/company/yandex/blog/169415/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку, будет очень интересно сравнить как альтернативу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

похоже, что ничего, кроме грамотного рефакторинга здесь не спасет =((

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь через Prepros любое количество файлов `.sass`, а в основном прописываешь

```
@import "_название"
```

(можно и без расширения, но обязательно с "_" в начале).

В итоге ты увидишь в компилированом css, что все подгрузилось.